# Koszul dual cooperad of the associative operad

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, category-theory, coalgebras, operads

I am trying to compute the $k$-modules of $\mathcal{As}^¡$, the Koszul dual cooperad of the associative operad $\mathcal{As}$. I am using sections 7.1.4 and 7.2.1 of [Algebraic Operads](http://irma.math.unistra.fr/%7Eloday/PAPERS/LodayVallette.pdf) to try to do this. I am also comparing what I am doing with [Derived A-infinity algebras in an operadic context](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5167) that descrbes this cooperad in the proof of proposition 2.7.

So I am tryng to express $\mathcal{As}^¡(n)$  as a $k$-module given by generators. The explicit definition from Loday and Vallette is given in terms of weight. More precisely, since $\mathcal{As}$ is generated by $E=k \cdot m_2$ concentrated in arity 2 and has the relator $R=k\cdot as=k(m_2\circ_1 m_2-m_2\circ_2 m_2)$,  concentrated in arity 3, we have a description of some of the direct summands of the Koszul dual in terms of their wieght

$\mathcal{As^¡}^{(0)}=(0, k Id, 0,0,\dots)$

$\mathcal{As^¡}^{(1)}=(0, 0, sE,0,0,\dots)$

$\mathcal{As^¡}^{(2)}=(0, 0, 0,s^2R,0,\dots)$

The $i$-th position represents arity $i$ (starting at $0$) and $s$ is the shift (say downwards) of grading. So it is clear that the generators of  $\mathcal{As}^¡(n)$ for $1\leq n\leq 3$ are respectively $\mu_1=Id$ of degree $0$, $\mu_2=sm_2$ of degree $-1$ and $\mu_3=s^2as=sm_2\circ_1 sm_2-sm_2\circ_2 sm_2$ of degree $-2$.

Now I am having problems in finding the generatorss $\mathcal{As}^¡(n)$ for $n>3$ because I am not sure of the explicit description of the whole cooperad. I now that the generators of $\mathcal{As}^¡(n)$ must lie in the weight $n-1$ component since we need to compose the binary operation $n-1$ times to obtain an arity $n$ operation. In particular, they are of degree $1-n$. I suspect that there is only one due to the associativity relation, but I am not sure if we are allowed to use this relation as a rewriting rule since it is being  used formaly as a generator.

In the same reference of Loday and Vallette (Section 3.1.3) there is a description for the Koszul dual coalgebra in which the analogue component to the weight $n$ has the general form

$(\bigcap_{i+2+j=n}sE^{\otimes i}\otimes s^2R\otimes sE^{\otimes j}\big)$

but I am not sure how this general term should look like for (co)operads.

Comment: Do you want to find an explicit generator of that intersection?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Well I don't know if that  intersection used for coalgebras is the same used for cooperads. And I guess I don't really understand that intersection because I see that it is trivial for most  of the cases. For instance, the weight 3 component here is $(sE\otimes s^2R)\cap (s^2R\otimes sE)$. Isn't this intersection $0$? The first space is 1-dimensional spanned by $sm_2\otimes s^2as$ and the second one is 1-dimensional spanned by $s^2as\otimes sm_2$.

Comment: That's not quite right! In fact the intersection you consider there is not entirely right. What you want is to consider operadic insertions instead of tensor products. Notice that such formula with intersections does not appear in Chapter 7.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff That's what I suspected, then how is that intersection written in the operadic context? Should I use the plethysm $\circ$, the operation $\circ_{(1)}$ or is it something different?

Comment: Yes, that is more or less the idea, but thinking about it the formula may be a bit more complicated than just replacing $\otimes$ with $\circ_{(1)}$. Is there any reason why you're not inclined to compute the annihilator of $R$ here (and hence the dual operad?)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff yes, I've been adviced to work with the dual cooperad instead of the dual operad because taking the linear dual has some complications. But well, even if there is not a so simple expression for the weight $n$ component, there must be a way to compute the generators of $\mathcal{As^¡}(n)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One has to be just a bit more careful about what that intersection means. A way to build the generator of $\mathcal {As}^\mathrm{dual}(n)=H^0(B(\mathcal As))$ is by taking a suitably signed sum of all binary trees in $\mathcal As(n)$.

Indeed, in arity two we simply take $m$, the product, and in arity three we take $r_2=m(m,1) -m(1,m)$. In general, the element you want will look like
$$ r_n = \sum_{T\in\mathsf{PBT_n}} (-1)^{\varepsilon(T)} m_T$$
where we take the sum over planar binary rooted trees and one has to choose the signs properly, and where by $m_T$ I mean the element in $B(\mathcal As)$ where we put $sm$ in the internal vertices of $T$. In arity four, the following choice works:

$$m(m(m,1),1) - m(m(1,m),1) + m(m,1)(1,m) + m(1,m(m,1)) - m(1,m(1,m))$$

where I write the fork $m(m,1)(1,m)$ since we need levels (since $m$ is actually of degree $1$ here, $m(m,1)(1,m)= -m(1,m)(m,1)$. Maybe you can figure out the correct signs in general! The picture is

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What condition should I check to decide if some signs are corrrect? In other words, what makes a choice of signs a correct choice?

Comment: @Javi That the bar differential of this is zero.

Comment: To add on Pedro's comment, the computation of $\mathcal{As}^¡$, with signs, is actually done in section 9.1.6, page 265 of Algebraic Operads.